.NET 8 Azure Function.ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() and synchronous operations are disallowed
For few months now I deploy .NET 8 azure function project with no issues.
Today it errored on any deployment attempt and I notice the error in program.cs that .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults() should be .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() see here.
After changing, all my responses started throwing an error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.Write

I found some ways to set AllowSynchronousIO to true but they relate to .NET Core 3 or 6. Nothing about .NET 8.
I know I could change to await response.WriteAsJsonAsync( but then I will have to change all the consumers of the APIs and it is a lot to change.
How can I add AllowSynchronousIO to true in my program.cs?
var host = new HostBuilder() 
                   .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
                   .ConfigureServices(services =>
                        {
                            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                            services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
                        })
                   .Build();
host.Run();

Any help? Thank you

Can you please share your function code

You still can use .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults() in your function. You need to use .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() if you intend to use ASP.NET core integration.

I am able to use response.WriteString(responseData); in my .NET8 isolated function


You still can use .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults() in program.cs file refer Start-up and configuration. You need to call .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() for ASP.NET Core integration.



If you are using .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults() then you should have below code in the mentioned files.

function.cs -
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _78408121
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var response = req.CreateResponse();
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
            return response;
        }
    }
}

program.cs -
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

.csproj -
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78408121</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


If you choose to use .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() then you should have below code in the mentioned files.

function.cs -
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _78408121
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var response = req.CreateResponse();
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
            return response;
        }
    }
}

program.cs -
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

.csproj -
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78408121</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I am getting expected response.
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5611 Commit hash: N/A +591b8aec842e333a87ea9e23ba390bb5effe0655 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.31.1.22191

[2024-05-02T08:53:19.367Z] Found C:\Users\***\source\repos\78408121\78408121\78408121.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-05-02T08:53:22.702Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 29100) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-05-02T08:53:22.746Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7045/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-02T08:53:27.815Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-05-02T08:53:33.028Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=c64ef602-184b-42cd-a32c-23f53cef5b26)
[2024-05-02T08:53:33.227Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-05-02T08:53:33.285Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=c64ef602-184b-42cd-a32c-23f53cef5b26, Duration=271ms)



There are some ongoing development in progress on the reported issue, refer this github issue.


Gem of an answer, showing package references and everything!

I added in Program.cs
 services.AddOptions<KestrelServerOptions>()
 .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
 {
     settings.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
     configuration.Bind(settings);
 });

and now it works fine. Thank you all.
